# Tiny shiny app to monitor pollinators: leaflet map rendering locally but not rendering online

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps

I work for a biodiversity monitoring project and I am trying to build a shiny app to better organize our fieldwork. I am basically trying to publish a map of our study area overlaid with a grid (our monitoring units). I am new to shiny apps and publishing stuff online but we really need that so I tried my hands at a tiny shiny app but failed:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap", height = 800))
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      rtp <- readRDS("./Data/rtp.RDS")
      
      m <- mapview(rtp,
                   method = "ngb", 
                   na.color = rgb(0, 0, 255, max = 255, alpha = 0),
                   query.type = "click",
                   trim = TRUE,
                   legend = FALSE,
                   map.types =  "Esri.WorldImagery",
                   alpha.regions = 0,
                   lwd=2,
                   color="red")
      
      output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({m@map})
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code works locally, as in I can see the map with the grid and interact with it. However, when I publish it (the app successfully deploys), all I get is a grey background with which I cannot interact and a small "Disconnected from server" note in the bottom left corner. I have no idea what to do.

The rtp grid file I used (only 12KB) can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C6ajG9nWKH15ysKYfoFf0y2xPJjzcG4x/view?usp=sharing)

Later, I plan to link this map to an online sheet (filled by field workers) within the shiny app to display fielwork progress.

Comment: Where are you deploying the app? Shinyapps.io? RStudio Connect?

Comment: @Marcus Shinyapps.io

Comment: Does it work when you load mapview as in `library(mapview)`?

Comment: @TimSalabim Yes, it works perfectly when I use mapview() !